# Probability question - Committee size

Tags: probability

A committee is formed by randomly selecting from eight nurses and two doctors. What is the minimum committee size that ensures at least a 90 % probability that it will not be comprised of nurses only?

Do we need to analyze this with cases?

Thank you!

Comment: yes omg thank you!

Comment: @AndréNicolas do you know how I would solve this?

Comment: I have written out an outline of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{10}{n}$ committees of size $n$. There are $\binom{8}{n}$ nurses only committees of size $n$. So the probability a committee is nurses only is $$\frac{\binom{8}{n}}{\binom{10}{n}}.\tag{1}$$

We want the ratio (1) to be $\le 0.1$. The numbers are small enough that probably a reasonable strategy is to try $n=2,3\dots$ until we get to or under $0.1$.

It would be more efficient to work backwards from $n=8$. The probability (1) is under $0.1$ at $n=8$ and $n=7$, but not at $n=6$.

Comment: why is it less than or equal to 0.1??

Comment: shouldn't it be less than or equal to 100% since you can't have 100% nurses on the committee?

Comment: We want a probability $\ge 0.9$ that it is **not** all nurses. So we want probability $\le 0.1$ that it is all nurses.